# App Store Downloading old version of app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have a big problem. My app got accepted for an update. It downloads the old version even though it is showing the new screen shot of the new version. (No biggie, I have read that it sometimes does this.) But as soon as i download it on my iphone4, the store gives the little red badge showing an update is needed, which is for my app. I download the new update, It gives the first page's new graphics, but as soon as i try to do anything in the app, it crashes. But it downloads the correct version for my iPhone 5!! D: I have tested everything on both devices. And everything worked perfect. Thanks in advance!!!

Kurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a day. It should adjust. Otherwise email apple support. Most likely won't take more than a few hours

Answer (score 1):

It can take a bit of time for the new version to propagate through all the various Apple store servers.  If you try it now, you're very likely to get the new version in all cases of downloading from all locations and stores.